# Выбор специализации шаблона на основе значения перечислений

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++03

проблема возникает при попытке реализовать CRTP похожий данный упрощенный пример:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

enum  ActionTypes {
    eInit      = 2 << 0,
    eUpdate    = 2 << 1,
    eMultUpdate = 2 << 2
};

template <class Data, 
          unsigned  Actions = eInit|eUpdate|eMultUpdate>
class ActionData
{
    template<ActionTypes As /*???*/>
    struct action {
        static void exec(Data*) { std::cout << "ActionData:: /*dummy*/ exec()\n"; };
        static void exec(Data*,int) { std::cout << "ActionData::/*dummy*/ exec(int)\n"; };
    };

    template<>
    struct action < /*???*/ > 
    {
        static void exec(Data*) { /*...*/ };
    };

    template< >
    struct action < /*???*/ >
    {
        static void exec(Data*, int) {  /*...*/  };
    };

    Data* derived() { return static_cast<Data*>(this); }
protected:
    void init()          { action<eInit>::exec(derived()); }
    void update()        { action<eUpdate>::exec(derived()); }
    void update(int key) { action<eMultUpdate>::exec(derived()); }
public:
    enum Keys { DEFAULT_KEY = -1 };

    void call(ActionTypes a, int key = DEFAULT_KEY)
    {
        switch (a) {
        case eInit:
            init(); break;
        case eUpdate:
            if (key == DEFAULT_KEY)
                update();
            else
        case eMultUpdate:
                update(key);
        }
    }

};

class Test : public ActionData<Test, eUpdate>
{
public:
    void update() { std::cout << "Test :: update()\n";  }
};


int main()
{
    Test actor;
    ActionTypes a = eInit;
    actor.call(a, 0); // useless here but must be possible.
    actor.call(eUpdate, 0);
    actor.call(eUpdate);
}
```

Не все наследуемые классы реализуют необходимые методы, если соответсвующий бит в маске не установлен,  action должен выбрать реализацию по умолчанию. На практике выбрать другую специализацию на основе параметра не являющегося типом невозможно, а решение, позволящие заменить его на класс, ускользает от меня.

*ПС. Оригинальное решение наследует интерфейс от большого проекта написанного на Си и переведенного на Си++.  ActionData Допустимыми возможностями являются возможности С++98/03 и tr1 С++11 (без вариадических шаблонов, без if constexpr, но enable_if  и пр. присутствуют).*

Comment: Что вы хотите реализовать? Что б метод не собирался для определенных Actions? Если да - то максимум что можно сделать - это "Linker error" для "неправильных" параметров, но ошибка линкера не выбрасывает на строку кода.

Comment: @nick_n_a Наоборот, он должен собираться, линкуя реалищацию по умолчанию. Смысл как раз в том чтоб собиралось всегда. Сторого говоря в случае шаблонов линковки не происходит, происходит подстановка, qed.

Comment: @Swift в том то и проблема, что значение устанавливается во время работы программы, а специализация шаблона - на этапе компиляции. Так что, увы (или к счастью) это невозможно сделать. Хотя возможен варинт, когда вы добавляете некий дефайн, в зависимости от значения которого компилятор собирает необходимый шаблон

Comment: @AndreyLevkovitch тут вы абсолютно не правы, как раз здесь все необходимое есть. как раз ватиант со сборкой правильного шаблона и имеется в виду. Более того в С++11 и выше реализуется тривиально, без специализаций ( есть if constexpr который можно применить внутри action). Моя проблема в отсутствии оного

Comment: Я чего-то не пойму в чём проблема тогда. Если у вас не получается обьявить процедуру вне контекста обьявления - то так и напишите. Внутри контекста лишние фигурные скобки ставить не нужно, и лишнее template не нужно (в вашем случае), константные параметры можно использовать в качестве константного литерала (Вместо 1 пишите Actions), вместо типа - можете указать шаблонный тип данных - компилятор позже подставит ваш тип. Вне контекста обьявления - правила чуть другие. Если компилятор выдаёт ошибку - так и напишите какую именно.

Comment: @nick_n_a Какие лишние скобки? Проблема в том что action должен быть шаблоном т.к. его содержимое разное определяемое на этапе компиляции. Шаблоны классрв нельзя перегружать, а шаблоны функций не могут иметь параметров по умолчанию

Comment: В чем именно у вас сейчас проблема? Что означает выбор специализации? Разные вызовы методов, разная работа одного метода, или что?

Comment: @nick_n_a SFINAE применительно к шаблону action с несколькими специализациями. В оформлении декларации action как и написано в вопросе.   Который бы позволил `action<eInit>::exec(derived())`  не выбрать реализацию  exec() по умолчанию  если соответвующий флаг был задан при определении Test.

Comment: Если не выбрать реализацию exec() по умолчанию, то выбирать какой метод именно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101359/discussion-between-swift-and-nick-n-a).

Comment: @nick_n_a из другой специализации шаблона ? (тут их тело не приведено, но они вызывают метод из  Data)

Comment: Хорошо, у вас есть `static void exec(Data*) ` вот и пишем реализацию  если поддержка Update `{ if (Actions & eUpdate ){ ... } else {  }` так не подходит если флаг задан?

Comment: @nick_n_a `if constexpr`. И можно тогда обойтись одной реализацией на все случаи. Только его нет

Comment: Из другой специализации этого же шаблона? Ну... можно. `void update() {  ActionData<Data,eUpdate>::exec( derived()); }`. Укажите из какого метода и какой вы хотите вызвать метод и с какими параметрами, тогда вам смогут показать подходящий пример. Статика вызывается через `::`, динамика через `->` плюс каст.

Comment: @nick_n_a возможно но несколько экстенсивно. Но наталкивает на идею. `action<eUpdate & Actions>::exec(derived())`?

Comment: Да, так можно, до тех пор пока в < > находятся константы, Actions  - у вас константа, и eUpdate - константа, а < > принимает константу. (при условии `template<int N>
    struct action {`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Весь секрет был в использовании частичных специализаций и учете возможности нулевого результата операции И

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

enum  ActionTypes {
    eInit      = 2 << 0,
    eUpdate    = 2 << 1,
    eMultUpdate = 2 << 2
};

template <class Data, 
          unsigned  Actions = eInit|eUpdate|eMultUpdate>
class ActionData
{
    template<ActionTypes A, typename Enable = void > struct action {};

    template< ActionTypes A >
    struct action<A, typename std::enable_if<(A & Actions) == 0>::type >
    {
        static void exec(Data*) { std::cout << "ActionData:: /*dummy*/ exec()\n"; };
        static void exec(Data*,int) { std::cout << "ActionData::/*dummy*/ exec(int)\n"; };
    };

    template< ActionTypes A >
    struct action < A, typename std::enable_if<(A & Actions) == eInit>::type  >
    {
        static void exec(Data* o) { o->Data::init(); };
    };

    template< ActionTypes A >
    struct action < A, typename std::enable_if<(A & Actions) == eUpdate>::type  >
    {
        static void exec(Data* o) { o->Data::update(); };
    };

    template< ActionTypes A >
    struct action  <  A, typename std::enable_if<(A & Actions) == eMultUpdate>::type >
    {
        static void exec(Data* o, int key) { o->Data::update(key); };
    };

    Data* derived() { return static_cast<Data*>(this); }
protected:
    void init()          { action<eInit>::exec(derived()); }
    void update()        { action<eUpdate>::exec(derived()); }
    void update(int key) { action<eMultUpdate>::exec(derived(), key); }
public:
    enum Keys { DEFAULT_KEY };

    void call(ActionTypes a, int key = DEFAULT_KEY)
    {
        switch (a) {
        case eInit:
            init(); break;
        case eUpdate:
            if (key == DEFAULT_KEY) {
                update();
                break;
            } else {
        case eMultUpdate:
                update(key);
                break;
            };
        }
    }

};

class Test : public ActionData<Test, eUpdate>
{
public:
    void update() { std::cout << "Test :: update()\n";  }
};


int main()
{
    Test actor;
    ActionTypes a = eInit;

    actor.call(a, 0);
    actor.call(eUpdate);
    actor.call(eMultUpdate, 0);
}
```